# PHP classes is this right

Tags: php, class

still getting used to PHP classes so a bit of "help /guidance" please

I have a class like this:

```
class ansa_accounturl_query {

    function __construct() {

     global $DBH;
     global $limit;
     $STH = $DBH->query("SELECT frm_url.frm_urlID,frm_url.frm_url FROM frm_url WHERE frm_url.accountID='SOMETHING' ".$limit." ");
     $STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);  
     $this->noforms = $STH->rowCount();  
     while($row  = $STH->fetch()): 
         $this->frm_urlID[]  = $row->frm_urlID;
         $this->frm_url[] = $row->frm_url;
     endwhile;
    }

}
```

The limit comes from a PHP function - and works.

What I would really like to do is create extend classes for  the above example which gives say `$this-frm_url` as a function. so that on the "page" I call the class `$classcall = new class();` but rather than have to go `echo $classcall->frm_url[$key];` I can just call a function like this `echo frm_url();` So in the example above there would be 2 extend classes one for frm_urlID and one for frm_url.

Also, in the "master class" am I right in in setting as array? i.e. `$this->frm_url[]` as without that I cannot seem to run a loop but the loop does seem "over" complex if you do it this way as you (well I) have to get a count of the array items then run the loop so you (again I) have a `for()` statement then a `foreach()`.  Seems longwinded to me.

Thanks in adavance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First:
Please do not use globals.
If you have to use "global" there is a 90% percent chance that your design is bad.
Either pass $DBH and $limit as parameters to __construct($dbh,$limit) or define them as static propertys of ansa_accounturl_query.
If you define them as static propertys the values will still be identical for all instance of your class.

Second:
If you want to call a method without creating a instance first you can declare the methods static, too. Then you can call them like this:

```
classname::myMethod(parameter);
```

if you allways use the same db and the same setting I would suggest you create a class with static propertys and 3 static methods.

Comment: Isn't it somewhat odd to say *dont use globals* but then suggest to use a static class? Static calls introduce the same depedency on the global scope as globals do.

Comment: At least they're encapsulated then.

Comment: I think he meant to not use "global" to bring external variables into scope. I would agree with that, since the "global" variable later on has no context. Static variables/classes at least put the variable in context. Sort of self documenting so you know where it was declared.

Comment: Yes that is what I meant. Scripts that use "global" tend to get messy. I have spend way to much time chasing down global variables  in complex projects :(

Comment: @Brent @Core please address comments to specific people with their names. Otherwise, they won't get notices of it. Discouraging globals while at the same time suggesting to use statics is like telling the OP not to drink the poison directly from the bottle but to use a glass. Statics are death to testability and should be avoided.

Comment: @Gordon One of the main drawbacks of statics is: they are hard to override and hard to test if they call other static dependencys(http://sebastian-bergmann.de/archives/883-Stubbing-and-Mocking-Static-Methods.html).IF THEY CALL THEM. In this case we are talikng about a simple call. The OP said he prefered to make a call without having aintance and a static is the best way to it. Of cause a proper architecture using neither globol nor statics(or ven singletons) would be the ideal solution. But I am afraid rebuilding the whole aplication structure would go way overboard.

Comment: @Oliver Seriously, what kind of argument is *if they call them*? What else would you write methods for if not to **call them**? Statics are bad **if they are the dependency** because statics are effectively globals and cannot be mocked with a double. That's what Sebastian and Misko are talking about. The point is, once you put `Foo::bar()` into anything but the global scope, you will have a dependency on the global scope and the class holding the method. You could just as well put `foo_bar()` into your code then. If you say "no globals", say "no statics" either. That's all I am saying.

Comment: @Oliver and to prove that it's not just *static methods calling static methods* but any static method hardcoded into your code, try to mock the DateTime class in the following piece of code `class Foo { public function bar() { return DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', '2010-12-14')->format('U'); } }`

Comment: You can not really mock statics but you canstill test them.But I admit it using tests on statics is a pain in the .... On the one hand I still think that static calls are exactly what the OP asked for, but on the other hand it is propably better if we just forget that dirty tricks like statics and globals exist.

Answer (score 0):

> What I would really like to do is
>   create extend classes for the above
>   example which gives say $this-frm_url
>   as a function. so that on the "page" I
>   call the class $classcall = new
>   class(); but rather than have to go
>   echo $classcall->frm_url[$key]; I can
>   just call a function like this echo
>   frm_url(); So in the example above
>   there would be 2 extend classes one
>   for frm_urlID and one for frm_url.

`echo frm_url();` won't work. You have to use `$classcall->frm_url[$key];` unless you define a function like

```
function frm_url($key){
  if (!$key) $key = 0;
  $classcall = new ansa_accounturl_query();
  return $classcall->frm_url[$key];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

 class ansa_accounturl_query {
   private static $FIND_ALL_QUERY = "SELECT frm_url.frm_urlID,frm_url.frm_url FROM frm_url WHERE frm_url.accountID='SOMETHING' %s"; 

   private $dbh;

   public function __construct( $dbh ) {
     $this->dbh = $dbh;
   }

   public function findUrls() {
      $query = $this->dbh->query(vsprintf($queryString, array( func_get_args() ) ) );

       $query->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);  

       $result = array();
       $result["count"] = $query->rowCount();
       $result["records"] = array();
       while( null !== ( $row  = $query->fetch() ) ) { 
          $result["records"][] = array(
              "id" => $row->frm_urlID,
              "url" => $row->rm_url
          );
       }

      return $result;
   }

}

$ansaQuery = new ansa_accounturl_query($DBH);
$result = $ansaQuery->findUrls();
foreach ( $result['records'] as $row ) {
   print sprintf("ID: %d; URL: %s", $row['id'], $row['url']);
}

print sprintf("URLs count: " . $result['count'] );
```